# Storing Time Difference Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, time

On my Django site, I am saving a user's reactions so when a user clicks a button, I store it as a created time and when the user clicks it second time, I stored the time as a finish time and so forth. Here it is my model;

```
class UserStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_TYPES = (
        ('online', 'online'),
        ('offline', 'offline')     
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_TYPES, default='online')
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_diff = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I added time_diff to show the time difference between created_time and finish time. When I try an example in the shell, I use;

```
user_status.created_time
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 12, 50, 21, tzinfo=<UTC>)
user_status.finish_time
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 12, 51, 37, 998593, tzinfo=<UTC>)
user_status.finish_time - user_status.created_time
datetime.timedelta(0, 76, 998593)
```

Everything seems to be fine until now, however when I wrote `user_status.save()` it gave an error;

> line 93, in parse_datetime
>       match = datetime_re.match(value) 
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer

I did not understand why it gave such an error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you try to use DateTimeField, but this field can only be used for storing date and time (but not time difference). You should use [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) for storing timedelta.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem. Actually I did not know "DurationField" :) and thought it is a parser problem or something like this :)